# How laravel uses object as an array in Facade class

Tags: php, laravel

I've noted that for creating a facade class, laravel provides only name "db"

**framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/DB.php**

```
class DB extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'db';
    }
}
```

I looked deeper and figured out that this method uses the provided name

**framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php**

```
protected static function resolveFacadeInstance($name)
{
    if (is_object($name)) {
        return $name;
    }
    if (isset(static::$resolvedInstance[$name])) {
        return static::$resolvedInstance[$name];
    }
    return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];
}
```

I understand first and second If statements.

But I have problems with understanding this:

```
return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name]
```

As I understood that `$app` is a protected property of `Facade` class which contains an instance of `\Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application` class.

```
/**
     * The application instance being facaded.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application
     */
    protected static $app;
```

My two questions:

How is it possible to use an object as an array(`static::$app[$name]`) if Application class doesn't extends ArrayObject class?

How laravel understands which class to call with providing only a short name 'db'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clicking through the Laravel source, I found this. As you can see, `ApplicationContract` (the `private static $app` from your question) is implemented by `Application`. This is in turn derived from `Container`, which implements the PHP core `ArrayAccess` interface. Carefully implementing this whole chain eventually makes `Applicatin` accessible like an array.

Turns out it boils down to good ole' object oriented programming :)

```
// Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
class Application extends Container implements ApplicationContract, HttpKernelInterface
                          ^^^^^^^^^            ^-> the private static $app in your question.

// Illuminate/Container/Container.php
class Container implements ArrayAccess, ContainerContract
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^

// PHP core ArrayAccess documentation
/**
 * Interface to provide accessing objects as arrays.
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php
 */
interface ArrayAccess {
```

Comment: Not everyone can dig into Laravel internals and know what the `Container` class is for, or how `ArrayAccess` is used to modify the behavior of a class. You should explain what these do and how it addresses the question.

Comment: Oof.. Do I? This is really just OOP basics like implementing interfaces and inheriting classes. `Application` derives from `Container` which implements `ArrayAccess`. I too don't know what Container actually does and how ArrayAccess is implemented, but OOP and documentation tells me that that is how Application is accessible as object. I'll update with some explanation though.

Comment: I understood you. Thanks. My mistake, I looked at Contracts directory, that is why I didn't find it

Comment: No problem. Cool question though! Didn't even know there was something like `ArrayAccess` so I've learned something too :)

Comment: Upvoted. The `Container` class is what's used to resolve object instances throughout the application. Laravel itself uses some clever reflection to guess how to instantiate an object that doesn't have a service provider through its [IoC Container](https://medium.com/@NahidulHasan/laravel-ioc-container-why-we-need-it-and-how-it-works-a603d4cef10f). ArrayAccess provides the contract necessary in pulling object instances out of the container without calling `$this->app->make()` through [offsetGet](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L1193)

Answer (score 0):

You can look this, php manual and use ArrayAccess interface:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php